# .htaccess - how to set headers dynamically per domain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cors

I'm trying to get CORS functioning with multiple domains.

```
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost, http://multiplay.io"
```

However, it seems that most browsers only support one domain. I've been told that the solution is to set the header per incoming domain.

How do you do this using the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's only two values you wish to alternate between, you can use `SetEnvIf` to differentiate between the two.

```
SetEnvIf Referer "^http://localhost/" is_localhost
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://localhost env=is_localhost
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://multiplay.io env!=is_localhost
```

There may be a more elegant solution, but something like the above (untested) directives should work.

(Note that it is trivial to forge a Referer header, so be aware of the security implications of forged Referer headers when using Referer headers for pretty much anything.)

Additionally, if you just want to allow all hosts, you can specify `*` instead of listing multiple hostnames:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

But I assume you already knew that and don't want to be that permissive.

Comment: Can I just create multiple `SetEnvIf ... is_domain_1 ... SetEnvIf ... is_domain_2` if I want to use more than 2 domains?